# How do I manipulate $\sqrt x - \sqrt y\over x-y$ into its alternate form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When solving a calculus problem, I came up with a difference quotient of $\sqrt x - \sqrt y\over x-y$. Wolfram Alpha tells me that it has an alternate form $1\over \sqrt x + \sqrt y$. How do I manipulate the first into the second?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$? If so, then $x-y$ is the difference of squares: $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) = x-y$.

Comment: Yes, I do. I was being stupid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt x-\!\sqrt y}{x-y}=\frac{\sqrt x-\!\sqrt y}{(\sqrt x+\!\sqrt y)(\sqrt x-\!\sqrt y)}=\frac1{\sqrt x+\!\sqrt y}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was bugging me to not know *why* I used an identity :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Could you do something with $\cfrac {a-b}{a^2-b^2}$

Comment: Thanks! Looking back at it, it was a very obvious transformation. But, as they say, hindsight is 20/20 :)